# Optimize MySQL FULLTEXT searches to use another index

Tags: mysql, index, full-text-search

I'm running a price comparison service, with a database of products that aims to become quite large (in the millions or more).

The `Product` table looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Product (
    id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    site_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    brand VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    name VARCHAR(500) NULL,
    variation VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX Product_Site (site_id),
    FULLTEXT INDEX Product_Fulltext (brand, name, variation),
)
```

Now I need to query products **belonging to a given site**, **using a search string**, which translates into this query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Product
WHERE site_id = 7
AND MATCH (brand, name, variation) AGAINST('something')
ORDER BY MATCH (brand, name, variation) AGAINST('something') DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**The query is not very fast**, even though my table is still quite small (< 1M).

The reason is given by `EXPLAIN`:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------------------------+
| id | select_type |  table  | partitions |   type   |         possible_keys         |       key        | key_len |  ref  | rows | filtered |            Extra              |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Product | NULL       | fulltext | Product_Site,Product_Fulltext | Product_Fulltext |       0 | const |    1 |    50.00 | Using where; Ft_hints: sorted |
+----+-------------+---------+------------+----------+-------------------------------+------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------------------------------+
```

It looks like MySQL is choosing to use the FULLTEXT index first, finding *all* rows that match the search string, then filter the rows that belong to the site I'm interested in. This is obviously highly inefficient.

And AFAIK:

- MySQL still cannot use two indexes in the same query,
- there is no way to have FULLTEXT act as a "hybrid" index that would be segmented by an integer `id`,
- partitioned tables do not support FULLTEXT indexes;

but I do hope that I'm missing something.

**Is there any way to speed up this query?** Or should I move away from MySQL to implement these searches? All suggestions welcome.

Comment: How many records (average) matches `site_id = 7` (or any another value)?

Comment: Anywhere from 5,000 to 100,000.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try (and let us know if it helps):

```
SELECT  p.*, ft.relevance
    FROM  (
        SELECT id,
               MATCH (brand, name, variation) AGAINST('something' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
            FROM Product
            WHERE MATCH (brand, name, variation) AGAINST('something' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
          ) AS ft
    JOIN Product AS p USING(id)
    WHERE p.side_id = 7
    ORDER BY  ft.relevance DESC
    LIMIT  10;
```

Also, provide `EXPLAIN FOMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.